# Running multiple instances of same springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, web-deployment, ovh

I've a spring-boot application which i want to deploy on OVH public cloud.

I need t achieve the goal of deploying multiple instances of the same application, and each instance has to have its own resources (such as MySQL database).

Each instance has to be accessed with a special url. For example:

- The first instance is accessable from http://domainname/instance1/index.html
- The second instance is accessable from http://domainname/instance2/index.html

I'm really new to everything which concerns cloud computing and deployments.

From what i read on the internet, my doubt is to

- Use Docker where each instance has to be running inside its own container (to have the resources separated for each instance)
- Use Kubernetes to achieve the goal of having each instance accessable from a specific url.

Am i wrong ? any online courses / resources / videos which can help would be awsome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) is a platform to develop, deploy, and run applications inside containers, therefore containers represent run-time environment for images. [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) plays the role as an orchestrator and provides sufficient way for building communication channels between containers in the cluster and uses Docker by default as a container runtime.

There are some essential [concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/) in Kubernetes that describe a cluster core [components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/) and application workload, thus define a desired state of the cluster.

Kubernetes [objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/#kubernetes-objects) represent abstraction level of cluster management operations  and containerized applications run-time environment within associated resources in Kubernetes API.

I would focus on the Kubernetes resources that are most crucial in application deployment lifecycle.

[Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is the main mechanism which defines how are Pods should to be implemented within a cluster and provides specific configuration for further application run-time workflow.

[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) describes a way how the particular Pod will communicate with other resources within a cluster, providing endpoint IP address and port where your application will respond.

[Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) exposes Kubernetes service outside the cluster with some exclusive benefits like load balancing, SSL/TLS ceritficate termination, etc.

You can get more relevant information about Kubernetes implementation in OVH within particular guide [chapter](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/kubernetes/).

Comment: Thanks, ingress was exactly the solution, sorry for late answer, i was reading about all those new things

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if it's a single application it should connect to one backend database, not 3 different databases.

If your use case is very specific and you really want to connect 3 instances of an application to 3 different databases then consider each deployed application as an independent application with 3 different deployments.

Talking about Docker and kubernenets, I don't feel you need these initially rather deploy your application directly to the cloud instances. To achieve the high availability of the application, deploy them as a part of autosacing group and map an ELB to each autoscaling group. Finally, map the ELB CNAME in your DNS record and start using your application.

Docker and K8s come with there own learning curve and adds overhead if you are new to this area. Though they have a lot of pros and are extremely beneficial if you have a lot of microservices to manage and have an agile environment.

My preference starts with VM first and then slowly move to the container world. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! well, the application is supposed to be sold to different customers and each one has to have it own data (not handling this in my application) that's why i want to deploy several instances of the same app with each instance having its database and i'm supposing each instance inside a docker container and kubernete for mapping each instance to its specific url, correct me if i'm wrong please

Comment: Ok! Still, I am not convinced. If that's the case, you need to deploy your application as statefulset in the k8s. I am not sure if we have a plugin for "OVH public cloud" in k8s to create the dynamic volumes.